# unable to open file which is in d: drive

Tags: c, windows, file-handling

How to read and write a file which is not in the bin directory that is it is out of the C drive.
I wrote this code

```
fs=fopen("d:/source.txt","w");
if(fs==NULL)
{
      puts("Unable to open file");
}
```

And it is outputting "Unable to open file". Can someone please help me out.

Comment: Use [`perror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/perror) instead to print the error, and it should tell you more specifically what's wrong.

Comment: I think your slash is backwards. What happens if you replace / with \\ (so that it's escaped)?

Comment: "C drive" suggests this is a Windows machine. In Windows, all paths are written using backslash. But since a backslash inside a C string has special meanings, you'd have to write `\\` to get one. So the path string should be `d:\\source.txt`.

Comment: But... a question of the nature "how do I correctly write a path in the Windows OS" is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Lundin But doesn't the Windows CRT allow both slashes as path separator? In fact, it seems Windows have *always* supported forward-slashes as separator. For example, try doing e.g. `dir "c:/some/path"` (note the quote characters) in a command window and you will see that it works fine.

Comment: The problem *may* be that you don't have write access rights to `D:\`, and that's why it fails. But it's just a guess. You really have to check the actual error.

Comment: I will also agree with @Joachim Pileborg.

Comment: thanks JoachimPileborg I will try it..

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE *fs= fopen("d:/source.txt","w");
if(fs==NULL)
{
  printf("can't open"); 
}
if (fs!=NULL)
{
    fputs ("Opened successfully",fs);
    fclose (fs);
}
```

Make sure the source.txt file exists and it is not read only. I tried above code didn't get any error.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible reasons why the file cannot be opened via [`fopen()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html).

To get information on details of the error print out [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and/or call [`perror()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) and/or [`strerror()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) like for example so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
  char filename[] = "d:/source.txt";
  FILE * fs = fopen(filename,"w");
  if (NULL == fs)
  {
    perror("fopen() failed");
    fprintf(stderr, "Error #%d occurred when trying to open file '%s': %s.\n", 
      errno, 
      filename,
      strerror(errno));
  }

  ... 

  return 0;
}
```